# How to get correct scale values?

Tags: qgis, scale

The scale of my map is wrong, no matter what coordinate system I use in my project. The map and all objects show the correct coordinates but the scale of the map shows nonsense and the measurement tool gives wrong dimension.

The map should be like 1:10000 but qgis shows 1:1. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you try to specify your question? What are you doing and what have you tried, yet? What kind of layers and what kind of coordinate reference system (CRS) are you using?

Comment: I wanna do a geological map. I have different shape files for lithologies and a basemap. All layers are set to WGS84 simple mercator at the moment. But I also tried other coordinate systems so far. Now the only thing that is wrong that the scale is not correct. I thought that th scale is logged to the coordinate system. like 1 degree equals xy kilometer.

Answer (score 6):

You must set the **Project** CRS to a projected CRS, for example the UTM zone for your part of the world. Thats different to the **layers** CRS, which might remain in degrees.

Measurement tool and scale bar look only at the project CRS, as long as on-the--fly-projection is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The CRS is also set to WGS84 simple mercator.

Comment: The shapefile comes with a .prj file. Can you open that in a text editor, and add the content to your question? I rather doubt that it came with "Simple mercator". And what do you use for basemap? And make sure "On-the-fly-projection" is checked.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. In the end it was the combination of CRS and and coordinate system of the shapefiles that was corrupted. Actually I did doublecheck that, but sometimes it helps to do the same things again and again....so thanks for your help!!!