# Scale mismatch on different platforms

Tags: qgis, scale, windows, linux, macos

I just started using QGIS. I need to work with QGIS on three different operating systems (Windows 11 (QGIS 3.26), MacOs 12 (QGIS 3.26) and Ubuntu 22.04 (QGIS 3.22)/Fedora 36-Linux(QGis 3.26).

I noticed a strange behavior on loading shape layers on different platforms - generally the scale should be about the same - but it isn't.

On Windows and Ubuntu the scale seems to be correct (see screenshot files) - on MacOs and Fedora the scale is completely different. Naturally this has for example implications on Labels, which are shown dependent on the scale - on MacOs and Fedora they seem never to appear unless I zoom extremely into the shapes.

I can see no difference in the Layer and project settings - can anybody give a hint what's wrong?

Screenshots:
[image: Ubuntu - Linux - Qgis 3.22]
[image: Ubuntu - Linux - Detail]
[image: MacOs - Qgis 3.26]
[[image: MacOs - Detail3]

Comment: Could it be that the Project's CRS are indeed not identical, but just the on the fly projection is enabled? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/45223/176374

Comment: What do you mean "the scale should be about the same"? You can change scale freely in any project. You also write about labels - but on your screenshot, I can't see any labels. So I'm not sure what exactly you're asking about.

Answer (score 1):

just by chance I stumbled across the solution - I guess:

In the project options under 'Messungen' (I guess 'measure') -> 'Ellipsoid' I had to choose 'GRS 1980 (EPSG:7019)' - That's been the difference...

[image: correct Values]